# .Net Core Identity seed data: unable to login using credentials seeded

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have my Initialiser setup and everything seems to run correctly and all the details are saved to the database but when I try to log in it via the webapp it fails everytime. When I run the debugger in the login controller it returns {Failed} after this is hit:

```
 var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

Initialiser:

```
public class DbInitialiser : IDbInitialiser
    {
       
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        public DbInitialiser(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;

        }

        public void Initialise()
        {
            try
            {
                if (_db.Database.GetPendingMigrations().Count() > 0) 
                {
                    _db.Database.Migrate();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
            }

            if (_db.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "Admin")) return;

            _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Admin")).GetAwaiter().GetResult();//makes sure this executes before proceceding with anything else
            _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Manager")).GetAwaiter().GetResult();



            _userManager.CreateAsync(new Employee       
            {
                UserName = "Admin",
                Email = "admin@gmail.com",
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                TwoFactorEnabled = false,
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = true
                //can set other properties, this is for the initial setup
            }, "Abc123!Abc123!").GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            IdentityUser user = _db.Users.Where(u => u.Email == "admin@gmail.com").FirstOrDefault();
            _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin").GetAwaiter().GetResult();


        }
```

(My Employee class extends IdentityUser)

I have checked all my password requirements as mentioned in other similar posts so I know it isnt to do with that and when I check in SSMS all the data for the user is there in aspnetusers so I am not sure why it wont let me login to the admin user that is seeded

Comment: If you register user through Register page, then login with new registered account, does it work well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I run the debugger in the login controller it returns {Failed}

In [the source code of `SignInManager<TUser>.PasswordSignInAsync` method](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/fcc02103aa10dcdd8759e0463cac2717114f3c1e/src/Identity/SignInManager.cs#L302), we can find it would check the user based on the provided `userName`.

```
public virtual async Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password,
    bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
{
    var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return SignInResult.Failed;
    }

    return await PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, isPersistent, lockoutOnFailure);
}
```

In your code, you set `UserName` with "`Admin`" that is not same as `Email` with "`admin@gmail.com`". If user login with email account, the code snippet `var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);` would return null, which cause the issue.

To fix it, you can try to set `UserName` with same value of `Email` (admin@gmail.com). Or modify the login code logic to find user by the Email, then sign in that user with password, like below.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);

        //var istrue = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, Input.Password);

        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);


        //var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
```

Comment: Ah I'm so silly. The email was originally the user name but I was playing around and changed it the other day. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `NormalizedEmail = "ADMIN@GMAIL.COM"` in Caps. Like this:

```
_userManager.CreateAsync(new Employee       
            {
                UserName = "Admin",
                Email = "admin@gmail.com",
                NormalizedEmail = "ADMIN@GMAIL.COM",
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                TwoFactorEnabled = false,
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = true
                //can set other properties, this is for the initial setup
            }, "Abc123!Abc123!").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```